# How to fill information into a template text file?

Tags: javascript

There is a separated template text file, which I want to use for generating content on my page. Currently I am using

```
string.replace("original", "target");
```

to replace the special string. I created a simple fiddle to show this.
http://jsfiddle.net/christinalam/0yow5zxt/

I wonder if there would be a more efficient way to do this.

Thanks

=== edit ===
I mean, is there any other way then using `string.replace`? it sounds in-efficient to me.

Comment: Are `_arg0_` and `_arg1_` always going to be in the template a single time?

Comment: I don't think what you have is really that bad as long as you are only replacing a single `_arg0_` and `_arg1_`.  If you want to replace multiple instances of those tokens then you might want to look into using a regular expression which is one of the overloaded versions of string.replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a blog post about a technique for doing this.  https://secureapplicationlifestyle.com/2014/10/tiny-template-engine-pattern-that-you.html
and there is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rg42apuh/

This technique locates a property name between a start and end delimiter and replaces that property name with a value.

The code looks like:

```
function ApplyTemplate(template, properties) {
    var returnValue = "";

    var templateFragments = template.split("{{");

    returnValue += templateFragments[0];

    for (var i = 1; i < templateFragments.length; i++) {
        var fragmentSections = templateFragments[i].split("}}", 2);
        returnValue += properties[fragmentSections[0]];
        returnValue += fragmentSections[1];
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

and you call it like this

```
var template =  "The quick {{Color}} {{Animal}} jumped over the lazy dog";

var values = {
    Animal: "fox",
    Color: "brown"
};

var result = ApplyTemplate(template,values);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store your template values in an object, then loop through the key/value pairs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo page</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="main">

    </div>
<script>
function populateTemplate(fileAsString, values){
  for(var key in values){
    if(values.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      fileAsString = fileAsString.replace("_"+key+"_", values[key]);
    }
  }
  return fileAsString;
}

function readTemplateFrom(file){
    return "_arg0_ Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, _arg1_ vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.";
}

/*var arg0="This is arg0.";
var arg1= "Time now is " + new Date().getTime();*/
var fileAsString=readTemplateFrom("templateFile.txt");
var values = {
    "arg0": "This is arg0",
    "arg1": "Time now is " + new Date().getTime()
};
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = populateTemplate(fileAsString, values);
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use replace(/_/gi, ''), can you gives us more clarity on this

```
string.replace(/_/gi, '');
```